# Choose a self-hosted email marketing software

Tags: email, email-server, newsletter

We have a newsletter of 250K contacts which keep growing. We send around 250 emails a month. We have been using Mailchimp and Brevo. Now, we are looking for their alternatives and thinking of using a self-hosted email marketing software.

The criteria are

1. We need to send and monitor both newsletters and transactional emails in one software.
2. Email deliverability. This is the most important. We can set up the system to make the email deliverability as high as possible.
3. User interface. It would be better if the user interface is not too old.
4. Tracking. We can track for instance if a contact has opened a newsletter or a transactional email.

I know that there are Sendy, MailWizz, etc. Could any recommend one based on the above criteria?